# Surface area of n-dim hyperspherical cap idea

Tags: integration, area, surface-integrals, beta-function, riemann-sphere

I want to calculate the surface area of an n-dim hyperspherical cap with radius r=1.
I found S. Li's evidence, but I don't understand his idea:
http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/ansinet/ajms/2011/66-70.pdf
His idea is for $\Phi \leq \pi /2$:
"The area of a hypershperical cap in a n-sphere can be obtained by integrating the surface area of an (n-1)-sphere of radius $\sin (\theta)$ with arc element $d\theta$ over a great circle arc:
$A^{cap}_n=\int_{0}^{\Phi} A_{n-1}(\sin (\theta))\ \,d\theta$

with the area of an n-sphere:
$A_n(r)=\frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma (n/2)} r^{n-1}$

I don't have much knowledge of Ana3 so I would be happy to receive detailed answers.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following image of concentric rings of constant width on a unit sphere:
[image]

The area of the circular ring with radius $\theta$ (measured on a great circle arc) and width $\Delta\theta$ can be approximated by $2\pi\sin(\theta)\cdot\Delta\theta$ if $\Delta\theta$ is small. So the area of a cap with radius $\Phi$ (again, measured on a great circle arc) is equal to the integral over the area of all these rings:

$$\int_0^{\Phi} 2\pi\sin(\theta)d\theta.$$

Note that $2\pi\sin(\theta) = A_2(\sin(\theta))$ is just the measure of the circle followed by the ring.

In higher dimensions, the same approach, dividing the area of the $n$-sphere into concentric $(n-1)$-spheres, yields the general formula you found.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your answer was spot on. Just two remaining questions: 1) in the first sentence after the pic is it "with radius $\sin (\theta)$"? 2) And $2\pi\sin (\theta)=A_2(\sin (\theta))$ instead of $...=A_1(\sin (\theta))$

Comment: The radius, as measured in 3D space, is $\sin(\theta)$, but the radius measured on the path along the surface of the sphere is $\theta$. This is important, as the width of a strip ($d\theta$) is the differential of the integrand ($\theta$). Also $A_1$ is correct, since we're integrating 1-dimensional measures to obtain a 2-dimensional measure.

Comment: So you mean by "radius measured on the path along the surface of the sphere is θ" the angle $\theta$, like in this sketch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnVpD.jpg ? \ I also don't unterstand why you are using $A_1$ if $A_n$ is difined as $A_n(r)=\frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma (n/2)} r^{n-1}$. So for the 3D sphere $A_2(\sin (\theta))=2\pi \sin (\theta)$ like in your explanation.

Comment: Ah, good point. $A_n(r)$ is the measure of $S^{n-1}$, not $S^n$.

Comment: Ok thanks:) One last point I don't really understand: for colatitude angels greater than $\Phi \geq \pi/2$ the formula does not work. So in this case i have to use $Area=A_n-A_{cap}(\theta)$. But i dont stand under why the integral decreases for angels over $\pi/2$. $\sin(\theta)$ is still the radius for rings with $\theta\geq\pi/2$.

Comment: I found out that this problem is due to the beta function used in the paper. I still don't know why the integral $A^{cap}_n=\int_{0}^{\Phi} A_{n-1}(\sin (\theta))\ \,d\theta=\frac{A_n}{2} I_{sin(\theta)^2} (\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{1}{2} )$ decreases for $\Phi > \pi/2$

Comment: The integral $\int_{0}^\Phi A_n(\sin(\theta))d\theta$ still increases for $\Phi > \pi/2$, but the integration method given in the paper no longer works, probably because there's a $sin^{-1}$ involved somewhere.